# Not able to write correct mysql join query

Tags: mysql, join

I have following 2 tables in mysql

```
1. Table-Name a

id int auto-increment PK
name varchar not null
year int(4) not null

2. Table-Name b
id int auto-increment PK
term varchar not null
a_id int FK references a.id
year int(4) not null
```

**1. data is as follow**

select * from a;

```
1,'Ravi',2010
2,'Kumar',2011
```

select * from b;

```
1,'a',1,2009
2,'b',1,2010
3,'c',1,2008
4,'d',2,2008
5,'e',2,2009
6,'f',2,2010
```

Now i wrote a query for result set that it should return a.id and count(b.id) if b table has a record with a.id and a.year=b.year

eg -

```
id | cnt
------------
1  | 1
2  | 0
------------
```

Here is my query -

```
select a.id,count(b.id) cnt from a
left join b
on b.a_id=a.id
where a.year=b.year
group by id;
```

which returns resultset -

```
id | cnt
------------
1  | 1
```

so behaviour is pretty obvious to me but i am not able to write query to get the resultset as i said earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause essentially converts `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You should move the predicate of `WHERE` to `ON`:

```
select a.id,count(b.id) cnt from a
left join b
on b.a_id=a.id AND a.year=b.year
group by id;
```

This way you get *all* `a` rows returned. If no match is found then `cnt` is going to be `0`.

Comment: It does work. thank you for the lession and +1 for the cause explanation